# Python can't find installed module, but pip can

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip, conda

Using a separate Virtual Environment using `conda`.
All the commands were run in that env.

```
❯ pip install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /home/v4g4x/miniconda3/envs/Scraping/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/v4g4x/miniconda3/envs/Scraping/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /home/v4g4x/miniconda3/envs/Scraping/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (2.2.1)
❯ python
Python 3.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2021, 16:45:57) 
[GCC 9.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
>>>
```

Output of `pip freeze`:

```
❯ pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2021.5.30
charset-normalizer==2.0.3
html5lib==1.1
idna==3.2
numpy==1.21.1
pandas==1.3.1
pathlib==1.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.26.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
urllib3==1.26.6
webencodings==0.5.1
wget==3.2
```

Here we can see that bs4(and hence beautifulsoup4) were installed and should be available. But `Python` can't find it during execution.

I've been using pip, conda and python envs for a while now. But I have no clue why it can't find that one package.

All the similar questions seem to be struggling between pip and pip3, but I do not have that issue, making it all the more difficult to understand.

Comment: Is it a fresh environment with no other packages? Does Python have trouble finding other packages? Could you try reinstalling bs4 with `python -m pip install --force-reinstall bs4`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `which pip`, maybe python and pip do not match.

Or you can install it with `python -m pip install`

Comment: This was a fix for me thank you!  But can you explain how to get "python and pip to match"?  Is it a reinstall of pip?

Comment: @NicoleGoebel you can use `python -m pip --version` find pip path, then alias pip or another name.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently even after `conda activate <env_name>`
`which python` seemed to be pointing at `/opt/splunk/bin/python` for some reason.
While `which pip` pointed to `<env_name>`.

That's the issue.

Comment: try `conda init <shell>`, and run `conda activate <env_name>` again.

Comment: I dunno it just went away in the afternoon. This only showed up in VS Code's integrated terminal. While it worked normally on the normal terminals.